OAuth 2.0 authentication issue in the Outlook add-in on the desktop version of Outlook for Mac
I'm developing an Outlook add-in using React.js in which MSAL library to implement OAuth 2.0 authentication. We are using msalInstance.loginPopup() for handling authentication. The add-in works perfectly on Windows, but for Mac outlook desktop application users are facing issues where the login process gets stuck.
Issue Description:
Expected Behavior: The add-in opens a popup via msalInstance.loginPopup() for users to log in through the OAuth 2.0 flow. After authentication, the access token should be returned and the popup closed.
Platform: Outlook for Mac Desktop application ( Mac Outlook web works fine ).
Problem: On Mac, the popup opens successfully, but users encounter a frozen login screen, and the OAuth process cannot be completed. This issue only affects outlook desktop for Mac users, as the flow works without problems on Windows.
Technical Setup:
Framework: React.js
OAuth Library: @azure/msal-react
Authentication Method: msalInstance.loginPopup()
Login Flow: OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow with PKCE
What I have tried:

Popup freezing on Mac outlook desktop: The popup opens fine, but after users input their credentials, the screen gets stuck, and the access token isn't returned. The popup doesn’t close, and users cannot proceed.
Browser behavior on Mac: We are able to successfully get access token for mac outlook web (browser: chrome, edge).

Questions:

Has anyone faced similar OAuth 2.0 issues on Mac outlook desktop? How did you resolve this issue?
Are there specific settings or configurations that ensure OAuth flow works across different environments, especially Mac?
How can I effectively debug this on Mac? Since developer tools aren't available inside Outlook for Mac, it's been hard to get error logs or insights into what's breaking the flow.

